# Adding a property if property matches some condition

Tags: sesam

What is the simplest way to add a computed property to the target entity only if the computed property matches some condition?

Given the following input entity:

```
{
  "_id": "foo",
  "bar": 5
  "baz": 10
}
```

And I want to add `foobar` if `["+", "_S.bar", "_S.baz"]` is greater than 15.

Answer (score 0):

This is one pattern that can be used (drawback is that you have to negate the conditional and remove after first adding the property which might feel a bit odd):

```
{
  "_id": "x",
  "type": "pipe",
  "source": {
    "type": "embedded",
    "entities": [{
      "_id": "foo",
      "bar": 5,
      "baz": 10
    }]
  },
  "transform": {
    "type": "dtl",
    "rules": {
      "default": [
        ["add", "foobar", ["+", "_S.bar", "_S.baz"]],
        ["if",
          ["not", ["gt", "_T.foobar", 15]],
          ["remove", "foobar"]
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to add the computed property as a temp variable like this:

```
{
  "_id": "x",
  "type": "pipe",
  "source": {
    "type": "embedded",
    "entities": [{
      "_id": "foo",
      "bar": 5,
      "baz": 10
    }]
  },
  "transform": {
    "type": "dtl",
    "rules": {
      "default": [
        ["add", "_tmp_foobar", ["+", "_S.bar", "_S.baz"]],
        ["if",
          ["gt", "_T._tmp_foobar", 15],
          ["add", "foobar", "_T._tmp_foobar"]
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The `_tmp_foobar` property will be removed when persisted to a dataset because it starts with an underscore, and can effectively be used as a temp property.